# How to provide *args and **kwargs to __call__ using abbreviated notation of class based decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a question about class based decorators in python and how arguments 
can be provided while decorating a given function.

Consider the following prototype:

```
class MyDecoratorClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # . . . Any code that is needed here
        pass

    def __call__(self, fun_to_decorate, *args, **kwargs):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # . . . Any code that is needed here
            return fun_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
```

And consider the function to be decorated:

```
def myfun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("myfun was called")
```

One way of decorating the above mentioned function would be the following:

- **Step 1:** Creating an instance of the decorator class. This will call the 
  constructor, that is, `__init__` . If I pass any argument 
  below, it would go "only once" inside `__init__` , when the instance is 
  created.

  decorator = MyDecoratorClass()
- **Step 2**: Specifying which function to be decorated, and if required provide 
  an argument list which will correspond to `*args` and/or `**kwargs` in 
  `__call__` signature as it has been defined in the class.

`decorated_fun = decorator(myfun, arg1, arg2)`

- **Step 3:** Finally call the decorated function and if required provide an 
  argument list for the function itself, which if provided, corresponds to 
  the list of the formal parameters of the inner function inside the `__call__` function.
  If I understand correctly, the namespace of inner formal parameters are distinct from the namespace of `__call__` formal parameters

  decorated_fun(...)

And this works. However if I want to use the abbreviated notation I have 
to write something like this:

```
@MyDecoratorClass(arg1, arg2)
def myfun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("myfun was called")
```

In the example above I passed the very same two positional arguments `arg1` and `arg2`. Now 
the problem is, that these two arguments are not `(*args, **kwargs)` specified 
in `__call__` but actually those specified in `__init__`

So my question is, when we use the abbreviated notation for decorating a 
function via a class based decoration with arguments, how to access **call**
argument list in order to provide those arguments **for each** decorated function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About decorator signature

Doing this...

```
decorated_fun = decorator(myfun, arg1, arg2)
```

... is not how decorators work. A decorator takes a *single argument*, a function, and outputs a function.

In particular, the above is not equivalent to the correct way to do which is this.

```
@decorator(arg1, arg2)
def myfun(...):
    ...

# Which is actually equivalent to...
myfun = decorator(arg1, arg2)(myfun)
```

### Accessing `__init__` arguments in `__call__`

If you want to have access to the argument passed to `__init__`, you could store them as instance attributes.

```
class MyDecoratorClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We store the arguments
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        # Any other code that is needed here


    def __call__(self, fun_to_decorate): # Single argument
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):

            # Here you have access to self.args and self.kwargs

            return fun_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner
```

### Doing the same with a function

Although, keep in mind that you do not need to have a class decorator to accomplish this, the following decorator will have the same behaviour.

```
def my_decorator_function(*args, **kwargs):

    def wrapper(decorated_func):

        def inner_wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs):
            # args and kwargs can be accessed here
            return decorated_func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)

        return inner_wrapper

    return wrapper

@my_decorator_function(arg1, arg2)
def myfun(*args, **kwargs):
    print("myfun was called")
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed description. When you said:

@decorator(arg1, arg2)
def myfun(...):
    ...

# Which is actually equivalent to...
myfun = decorator(arg1, arg2)(myfun)

I don't understand this syntax of function call (I'm a beginner), shouldn't all arguments of a function call be like (a1, a2, . . .)? What you suggests is fun (a1, a2) (...) I don't know this syntax.

Comment: It's because in this example `decorator` is a function that takes `arg1` and `arg2` and return a function that in turn takes `myfun`. Like `my_decorator_function` by example.

Comment: I see, so decorator(arg1, arg2) becomes a function expression itself (I mean it's result), and the whole expression decorator(arg1, arg2) (my fun) becomes the final function call. Right?

Comment: Correct! Functions can return functions.