# Decorated and wrapped function is not passing self to instance method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to run some instance methods as background threads using a decorator. Several nested functions are chained (as found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211813/7216865)) to make it work:

```
import traceback
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread


def backgroundThread(name=''):
    def fnWrapper(decorated_func):
        def argsWrapper(name, *inner_args, **inner_kwargs):
            def exceptionWrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()

            if not name:
                name = decorated_func.__name__

            th = Thread(
                name=name,
                target=exceptionWrapper,
                args=(decorated_func, ) + inner_args,
                kwargs=inner_kwargs
            )
            th.start()

        return partial(argsWrapper, name)

    return fnWrapper


class X:
    @backgroundThread()
    def myfun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        print("myfun was called")
        #1 / 0


x = X()
x.myfun(1, 2, foo="bar")
x.myfun()
```

Output/Error (on Windows, Python 3.6.6):

```
(2,) {'foo': 'bar'}
myfun was called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t3.py", line 11, in exceptionWrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: myfun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The code works partly, how to be able to 'bind' `self` to the call: `x.myfun()` which takes no arguments ?

Comment: Maybe you should use `functools.partialmethod()` instead of `functools.partial()`.

Comment: @chepner no, `name` comes from the default argument for the `backgroundArgs` decorator. `self` is passed to `myfun` from the explicit arguments (not `x`), because method binding does not occur, because `functools.partial` objects do not support it. See my answer for a complete explanation.

Comment: Yeah, after I saw your answer (especially the point about `partial` not being a descriptor), I rethought my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, the problem is that `@backgroundThread()` doesn't wrap an instance method `x.myfun`; it wraps the function `X.myfun` that is namespaced to the class.

We can inspect the wrapped result:

```
>>> X.myfun
functools.partial(<function backgroundThread.<locals>.fnWrapper.<locals>.argsWrapper at 0x7f0a1e2e7a60>, '')
```

This is not usable as a method, because `functools.partial` is not a descriptor:

```
>>> X.myfun.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__get__'
>>> class Y:
...     # no wrapper
...     def myfun(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print(args, kwargs)
...         print("myfun was called")
...         #1 / 0
... 
>>> Y.myfun.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x7f0a1e2e7940>
```

Because `X.myfun` is not usable as a descriptor, when it is looked up via `x.myfun`, it is called like an ordinary function. `self` does not receive the value of `x`, but instead of the first argument that was passed, resulting in the wrong output for the `(1, 2, foo='bar')` case and the exception for the `()` case.

---

Instead of having `argsWrapper` accept a `name` and then binding it with `partial`, we can just use the `name` from the closure - since we are already doing that with `decorated_func` anyway. Thus:

```
def backgroundThread(name=''):
    def fnWrapper(decorated_func):
        def argsWrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs):
            nonlocal name
            def exceptionWrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()
            if not name:
                name = decorated_func.__name__
            th = Thread(
                name=name,
                target=exceptionWrapper,
                args=(decorated_func, ) + inner_args,
                kwargs=inner_kwargs
            )
            th.start()
        return argsWrapper
    return fnWrapper
```

Here, `nonlocal name` is needed so that `argsWrapper` has access to a name from a scope that is not the immediate closure, but also isn't global.